# pass data with Button in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I try to pass data from my `ViewController` to `TableViewPlace.swift`Use the buttons. When I am choosing button return not some thing

**viViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    struct Country{
        var id :Int
        init(id:Int){

            self.id = id
        }
}
var CountrySelected = [Country]()
var countryArry = NSArray()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func airAction(sender: AnyObject) {
}


@IBAction func viewPlaceAction(sender: AnyObject) {


    getParsePlaceView()
     // json viewPlace


    performSegueWithIdentifier("viewPlaceSegu", sender: sender)
}

@IBAction func tourAction(sender: AnyObject) {
}
/// Open the page
    // parse json
func getParsePlaceView(){

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!){ [unowned self] (data , repsonse , error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        } else {

            do {
                let posts = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

                for post in posts {

                    if let id = post["userId"] as? Int{

                     // print(id)

                        let sets = Country(id: id)
                        self.CountrySelected.append(sets)
                    }


                }
                self.countryArry = posts
                print(self.countryArry)// return data and currect

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()

   print(countryArry) // return nil why??
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // get a reference to the second view controller
    if segue.identifier == "viewPlaceSegu" {
        if let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? TableViewPlace {

            // set a variable in the second view controller with the String to pass
            print(countryArry)
            secondViewController.tnt = countryArry
        }

    }
}


}
```

when I `print(countryArry)` return nil  why ??

Can someone help me or give me a better solution?

Comment: tnt is `ViewController` and country is `[Post]` object .. so error suggest the same thing

Comment: I didn't know what to do ?

Comment: upadte code . and problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `Post` object with this line :

```
let countryPlace = Post(userid: post["userId"] as! Int, title: post["title"] as! String)
```

And you are trying to pass to your tableview this `Post` object to your `tnt` variable which is a `ViewController` class, this is why you've got the first error :

```
secondViewController.tnt = Country
```

Then, if you want to add your string country to your mutable array you have to do :

```
if let title = tnt.title {
   Country.append(title)
}
```

Comment: error 2 solved. But for the first error , I didn't know what to do ?

Comment: If you want to pass to your tableview your `Post Country` object, you have to transform the line  `var tnt: ViewController!` into this : `var tnt: [Post]!`

Then the  `tnt` variable will contain your `Post Country` object

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what i should .

Comment: change `var tnt: ViewController!`
by `var tnt: [Post]!`

Comment: put 

`var CountrySelected = [Country]()
var countryArry = NSArray()`

in : 
`override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
var CountrySelected = [Country]()
var countryArry = NSArray()
}`